# Changing selected text layers language with photoshop script

Tags: javascript, photoshop, extendscript, photoshop-script

Though I managed to put a functional script to change the dictionary language of selected layers together, it's not quite what I need yet.

I'm currently retrieving the index of my selected layers, using them to get the layer names—*it's the problematic part*—then working the magic to change their language based on an option chosen in a custom dialog box I display.

The use of layers names is a very half-assed solution, I need precision, I need to be able to change the language based on a layer ID or index. Not only my script is prone to names conflicts but I have no idea of where those selected layers will be, if on the root of the document or inside 5 groups stack.

Here is my current code:

The main function

```
function main() {
    // Create window with language selection and retrieve selected value
    var lang = createWindow();

   // Retrieve selected layers
   var selectedLayers = getSelectedLayersIdx();

   // Look at each entry and change language when possible
   for(var a in selectedLayers){
        try {
           setLangByIndex(Number( selectedLayers[a]), lang );
        } catch(err) {   }
   }
}
```

(*createWindow* returns a lang value, skipping that)

Mike's get Idx

```
function  getSelectedLayersIdx(){
    var selectedLayers = new Array;
    var ref = new ActionReference();
    ref.putEnumerated( charIDToTypeID('Dcmn'), charIDToTypeID('Ordn'), charIDToTypeID('Trgt') );
    var desc = executeActionGet(ref);
    if( desc.hasKey( stringIDToTypeID( 'targetLayers' ) ) ) {
        desc = desc.getList( stringIDToTypeID( 'targetLayers' ));
        var c = desc.count
        var selectedLayers = new Array();
        for(var i=0;i<c;i++) {
            try{
                activeDocument.backgroundLayer;
                selectedLayers.push(  desc.getReference( i ).getIndex() );
            } catch(e) {
                selectedLayers.push(  desc.getReference( i ).getIndex()+1 );
            }
        }
    } else {
        var ref = new ActionReference();
        ref.putProperty( charIDToTypeID('Prpr') , charIDToTypeID( 'ItmI' ));
        ref.putEnumerated( charIDToTypeID('Lyr '), charIDToTypeID('Ordn'), charIDToTypeID('Trgt') );
        try {
            activeDocument.backgroundLayer;
            selectedLayers.push( executeActionGet(ref).getInteger(charIDToTypeID( 'ItmI' ))-1);
        } catch(e) {
            selectedLayers.push( executeActionGet(ref).getInteger(charIDToTypeID( 'ItmI' )));
        }
    }
    return selectedLayers;
}
```

The function which sets the language

```
function setLangByIndex(idx, lang){
    ref = new ActionReference();
    ref.putProperty( charIDToTypeID("Prpr") , charIDToTypeID( "Nm  " ));
    ref.putIndex( charIDToTypeID( "Lyr " ), idx );
    var name = executeActionGet(ref).getString(charIDToTypeID( "Nm  " ));

    var el = activeDocument.layers.getByName( name );
    // Temp quick block; MUST UPDATE IN CASE OF NEW LANGUAGES
     if (lang == 'pt_br' )
        el.textItem.language = Language.BRAZILLIANPORTUGUESE;
    else if (lang == 'en_us' )
        el.textItem.language = Language.ENGLISHUSA;
    else
        el.textItem.language = Language.ENGLISHUK;
}
```

Workarounds I inefficiently tried:

- Use Adobe's script listener to change the language with an *executeAction*,
  but couldn't make it work. The language part is inside ~4 stacked
  descriptors (and a list!). I got lost and kept getting errors 8800.
- Figure out how obtain an object ref by using the idx. Failed
  miserably.

Comment: A little difficult to debug without a sample PSD. Possible for you to upload a very simplified PhotoShop document? And if you are uploading, can you also upload these scripts as well.

Comment: I gave it another try this morning and got it working! The Script Listener output I used can be found here: http://pastebin.com/U9fQKLvG

Here is my current script: http://pastebin.com/kZf8aeDY
I won't post it as an answer yet just to see if someone has a better suggestion (my coding skills are puny!). I used the complete _set_ Action because the Override doesn't accept an idx.

The PSD example (I don't think it's needed anymore, but...): http://goo.gl/C9SdNu
It's worth noting the files I'll be using this script on varies drastically, thus a script shouldn't be tailored for this example only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I noticed some annoying glitches related to Paragraph Styles (the ones you can define as the default for your text on PS, not the JS object) I gave up on being stubborn and stopped avoiding doing a new loop through the indexes array to reselect the layers when done.

```
/*
   *  Based in Mike Hale's "getSelectedLayersIdx" script and Adobe's Scripting Listener dump.
      Based the panel on Davide Barranca's code: http://www.davidebarranca.com/2012/10/scriptui-window-in-photoshop-palette-vs-dialog/

      Useful Resources:
      Photoshop char list: http://www.pcpix.com/Photoshop/char.htm
      ActionDescriptor methods: http://jongware.mit.edu/pscs5js_html/psjscs5/pc_ActionDescriptor.html
      TextItem methods: http://jongware.mit.edu/pscs5js_html/psjscs5/pc_TextItem.html
      You can fish for language codes here: http://wingp.googlecode.com/svn/photogp/photoshopapi/photoshop/PIStringTerminology.h
*/

/* ______________________________ SCRIPT ______________________________ */
var scriptAlert = "Language Change says";

// MUST UPDATE IF YOU WANT TO CHANGE THE AVAILABLE LANGUAGES
// The available languages, as { text displayed on dialog window : codename }. See notes above for more language codes
var langs = {};
langs['Português (Brasil)'] = 'brazilianPortugueseLanguage';
langs['English (UK)'] = 'ukenglishLanguage';
langs['English (USA)'] = 'englishLanguage';

if(app.documents.length>0){ // the script will be executed  only if an active document exists.

    var imgName = activeDocument.name;
    var extreme= imgName.substr(imgName.length - 5, 5);
    var dot = extreme.lastIndexOf(".");

    if(dot == -1) { // Checks if the active document  was saved or not.
        alert("Please, save your document!", scriptAlert, false);
    } else {
        main(); // if the active document was saved, go ahead! 
    }
}


function createWindow() { // Creates a panel asking for input
        var isDone, win, windowResource, radio_group, cancel, rb, i;

        //sentinel variable
        isDone = false;
        cancel = false;

        // Build dialog radio buttons
        i = 0;
        for( var k in langs ) {
            if( i==0 )
                rb = "rb"+i+": RadioButton { text:  '"+k+"', value: 1 }, \ ";
            else
                rb += "rb"+i+": RadioButton { text:  '"+k+"' }, \ ";
            i++;
        }

        windowResource = "palette {  \
            orientation: 'column', \
            alignChildren: ['fill', 'top'],  \
            preferredSize:[300, 130], \
            text: 'Change Spell Check Language',  \
            margins:15, \
            \
            optPanel: Panel { \
                orientation: 'row', \
                alignChildren: 'left', \
                margins:15, \
                text: ' Select the desired dictionary language for the select text ', \ "+  rb + " \
                } \
            \
            bottomGroup: Group{ \
                cancelButton: Button { text: 'Cancel', properties:{name:'cancel'}, size: [120,24], alignment:['right', 'center'] }, \
                applyButton: Button { text: 'Ok', properties:{name:'ok'}, size: [120,24], alignment:['right', 'center'], active: true }, \
            }\
        }";
        win = new Window(windowResource);

        radio_group = win.optPanel; // set group

        // Match options with language
        function selected_rbutton (rbuttons)
        {
             for (var i = 0; i < rbuttons.children.length; i++)
                 if (rbuttons.children[i].value == true)
                    return langs[rbuttons.children[i].text];
         }

        win.bottomGroup.cancelButton.onClick = function() {
            win.close();
            return cancel = true;
        };      
        // Button listeners
        win.bottomGroup.applyButton.onClick = function() {
          return isDone = true;
        };             
        // don't forget this one!
        win.onClose = function() {
            return cancel = true;
        };

        win.addEventListener("keydown", function (k)
         {
             if (k.keyName == 'Enter')
                return isDone = true;
         });

        win.show();

        while (isDone === false) {
            try {
                app.refresh();
            } catch(err) { // Esc cancels without errors
                return false;
            }
        }

       return cancel ?  false : selected_rbutton (radio_group); // return value, or false if cancelled
}


function  getSelectedLayersIdx(){ // Gets array of indexes of selected layers
    var selectedLayers = new Array;
    var ref = new ActionReference();
    ref.putEnumerated( charIDToTypeID('Dcmn'), charIDToTypeID('Ordn'), charIDToTypeID('Trgt') );
    var desc = executeActionGet(ref);
    if( desc.hasKey( stringIDToTypeID( 'targetLayers' ) ) ) {
        desc = desc.getList( stringIDToTypeID( 'targetLayers' ));
        var c = desc.count
        var selectedLayers = new Array();
        for(var i=0;i<c;i++) {
            try{
                activeDocument.backgroundLayer;
                selectedLayers.push(  desc.getReference( i ).getIndex() );
            } catch(e) {
                selectedLayers.push(  desc.getReference( i ).getIndex()+1 );
            }
        }
    } else {
        var ref = new ActionReference();
        ref.putProperty( charIDToTypeID('Prpr') , charIDToTypeID( 'ItmI' ));
        ref.putEnumerated( charIDToTypeID('Lyr '), charIDToTypeID('Ordn'), charIDToTypeID('Trgt') );
        try {
            activeDocument.backgroundLayer;
            selectedLayers.push( executeActionGet(ref).getInteger(charIDToTypeID( 'ItmI' ))-1);
        } catch(e) {
            selectedLayers.push( executeActionGet(ref).getInteger(charIDToTypeID( 'ItmI' )));
        }
    }
    return selectedLayers;
}


function selectLayerByIndex( selectedLayers, add ){ // Selects layers by index. If fed an array + true add, selects them, otherwise provide a single value so it selects a single layer
    if (typeof(add)==='undefined') add = false;

    if ( add ) // If Add it's an array
        for(var a in selectedLayers){
            var desc = new ActionDescriptor();
                var ref = new ActionReference();
                ref.putIndex( charIDToTypeID( "Lyr " ), Number(selectedLayers[a]) );
            desc.putReference( charIDToTypeID( "null" ), ref );
            desc.putEnumerated( stringIDToTypeID( "selectionModifier" ), stringIDToTypeID( "selectionModifierType" ), stringIDToTypeID( "addToSelection" ) );
            var idMkVs = charIDToTypeID( "MkVs" );
            desc.putBoolean( charIDToTypeID( "MkVs" ), false );

            executeAction( charIDToTypeID( "slct" ), desc, DialogModes.NO );
        }
    else // Else I just need to make this layer active, it's a number
    {
            var desc = new ActionDescriptor();
                var ref = new ActionReference();
                var idLyr = charIDToTypeID( "Lyr " );
                ref.putIndex( charIDToTypeID( "Lyr " ), selectedLayers );
            desc.putReference( charIDToTypeID( "null" ), ref );
            desc.putBoolean( charIDToTypeID( "MkVs" ), false );
        executeAction( charIDToTypeID( "slct" ), desc, DialogModes.NO );
    }
}


function setLangByIndex( idx, lang ){ // Sets the dictionary language for a text layer based on its index
// Make layer active
    selectLayerByIndex( idx );

// And do tiny override
    var textObj = new ActionDescriptor();
        var target = new ActionReference();
        target.putProperty( charIDToTypeID( "Prpr" ), charIDToTypeID( "TxtS" ) ); // desired property: text style
        target.putEnumerated( charIDToTypeID( "TxLr" ), charIDToTypeID( "Ordn" ), charIDToTypeID( "Trgt" ) ); // the active layer
    textObj.putReference( charIDToTypeID( "null" ), target );
        var textStyle = new ActionDescriptor();
        textStyle.putInteger( stringIDToTypeID( "textOverrideFeatureName" ), 808466225 );
        textStyle.putInteger( stringIDToTypeID( "typeStyleOperationType" ), 3 );
        textStyle.putEnumerated( stringIDToTypeID( "textLanguage" ), stringIDToTypeID( "textLanguage" ), stringIDToTypeID( lang ) );

    textObj.putObject( charIDToTypeID( "T   " ), charIDToTypeID( "TxtS" ), textStyle ); // to (end); text style, desc.
executeAction( charIDToTypeID( "setd" ), textObj, DialogModes.NO ); // execute
}


////////////////////////////////////
// Main function
function main() {
    // Create window with language selection and retrieve selected value
    var lang = createWindow();

    if ( !lang ) // If cancelled please stop
        return;

     // Retrieve selected layers
     var selectedLayers = getSelectedLayersIdx();

    // Look at each entry and change language when possible; otherwise skip to next item
    for(var k in selectedLayers){
       try {
            setLangByIndex(Number(selectedLayers[k]), lang);
        } catch(err) {
            continue;
        }
    }
    selectLayerByIndex( selectedLayers, true );
}
```